# Sencha Touch : Refresh Store Content

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2-proxy

I want to Refresh my store content, I have a to display list of tickets and for each ticket there are list of attachments. Attachments are optional so For a ticket there maynot be an attachment.

I am using Odata proxy based on Rest Proxy.

I have 2 separate store for ticket and attachment. If I load the attachment store based on a ticket which has attachment, the store gets populated, now when I select a ticket which has no attachment the store doesnt get refreshed but is showing me the store content from the previous ticket. If I try to use "RemoveAll" method on the store, the store tries delete the entries in the Backend system which  I dont want. I just want the store to refresh its content on each request.

what is the way to reload the store and refresh its content

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try with:

```
Ext.getStore('myStore').load();
```

Comment: in case the user isn't aware the string passed to the getStore function is the value set in your storeId property when defining your store.